How to take printscreen from Hostexplorer and paste in MS Word
Good day. I am using Host explorer version 15.0.7 and tried creating a VBA MACRO to take the screenshot from the Mainframe to MS Word Document. As I am a newbie to this Macro, I am looking for assistance in order to achieve the requirement. I presume this can be achieved by either issuing Printscreen key command or Copy and paste the screenshot to Clipboard and paste to MS Word document.
As per the Help document from Host explorer, it shows to use the print screen key as "@P@t" and might use the DLL libraries like ehlapi32.dll or egllap32.dll.
My VBA code struck with error at the very first line of my code.
Private Declare Function WD_ConnectPS Lib "ehlapi32.dll" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal ShortName As String) As Integer
If I comment that line and debug for any errors, it is stopping in the following line
HostExplore.ActiveSessions.SendKeys "@P@t" or
HostExplore.ActiveSessions.SendKeys "%{Prtsc}"
Could anyone advise how to fix this error as my main intent was to take the print screen of the current Mainframe screen and paste it into MS Word.
Private Declare Function WD_ConnectPS Lib "Path of my DLL file\ehllap32.dll" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal ShortName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Function WD_ConnectPS Lib "Path of my DLL file\ehlapi32.dll" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal ShortName As String) As Integer
Sub Main
Dim Host As Object
Dim HE As Object
Dim appWD As Object

Set HE = CreateObject("HostExplorer")
Set Host = HE.CurrentHost

'*  SendKeys "%{PRTSC}"     /* Sends Print screen key
'*  Host.Runcmd("@A@P")     /* It executes printscreen key (@A@P or @A@t) function in Hostexplorer terminal
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWD.AppShow
appWD.FileNewDefault
appWD.Visible=True
appWD.Documents.Add
appWD.Selection.Paste
appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs("filepath")
appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
appWD.Quit
set appWD = Nothing

End Sub
Appreciate your time.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Updated my query with the existing code. Thanks
